# SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, ssl, spring-integration, keytool

I've seen other questions with this error, but most are not using Spring Integration. The one I saw that did use Spring Integration was due to a corrupt keystore. I have re-created my keystores and truststores many times, so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

I am trying to enable TLS between my `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` and `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory`. Here is my Spring config:

```
@Bean
public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 6000);
    factory.setTcpSocketFactorySupport(sslSocketFactorySupport(
            "security/empty.jks",
            "security/client-truststore.jks",
            "changeit",
            "changeit"));
    factory.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport());
    factory.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
    factory.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory() {
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(6000);
    factory.setTcpSocketFactorySupport(sslSocketFactorySupport(
            "security/server.jks",
            "security/empty.jks",
            "changeit",
            "changeit"));
    factory.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport());
    factory.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
    factory.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport sslSocketFactorySupport(String keyStore, String trustStore, String keyStorePassword, String trustStorePassword) {
    TcpSSLContextSupport contextSupport = new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport(keyStore, trustStore, keyStorePassword, trustStorePassword);
    return new DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport(contextSupport);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow requestFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(serverConnectionFactory()))
            .<byte[]>handle((p, h) -> MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload(p)
                    .build())
            .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(serverConnectionFactory()))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow responseFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(clientConnectionFactory()))
            .channel(MessageChannels
                    .queue("responseChannel")
                    .get())
            .get();
}
```

The `empty.jks` file is an empty keystore. Here are the commands I used to generate my server keystore and client truststore:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

keytool -genkey \
        -keypass changeit \
        -storepass changeit \
        -keystore src/main/resources/security/server.jks

keytool -export \
        -storepass changeit \
        -file src/main/resources/security/server.cer \
        -keystore src/main/resources/security/server.jks

keytool -import \
        -v \
        -trustcacerts \
        -file src/main/resources/security/server.cer \
        -keypass changeit \
        -storepass changeit \
        -keystore src/main/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
```

Finally, here's a simple test to send a `Message` back and forth between my two connection factories. Without TLS, it works fine. With TLS, I get SSL read exceptions about cipher suites.

```
@Autowired
private TcpNetClientConnectionFactory client;

@Autowired
private QueueChannel responseChannel;

@Test
public void requestAndResponse() throws Exception {
    Message<byte[]> request = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload("foo".getBytes())
            .build();

    client.getConnection().send(request);

    assertNotNull(responseChannel.receive(1000));
}
```

What is wrong with my SSL setup?

### UPDATE

I am using Java 8. Here are the client ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

server ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CB    C_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA    _WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_12    8_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_E    CDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AE    S_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_    SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

I can see right off the bat that the first one matches.

### UPDATE 2

Using `javax.net.debug=all`, here is the ClientHello:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1567538676 bytes = { 28, 158, 236, 83, 48, 241, 225, 168, 30, 197, 146, 201, 129, 246, 199, 156, 9, 78, 61, 157, 11, 64, 25, 26, 41, 181, 233, 45 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
```

I see the raw write of the ClientHello (204 bytes), and then a raw read of 5 bytes and then 199 bytes. Interestingly enough, after the raw read is formatted, it appears to be another ClientHello, not a ServerHello:

```
pool-1-thread-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 199
 C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1567539109 bytes = { 119, 78, 120, 53, 121, 162, 190, 126, 136, 74, 228, 139, 71, 227, 132, 120, 177, 116, 234, 187, 14, 134, 253, 158, 109, 174, 41, 17 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
```

followed quickly by this:

```
pool-1-thread-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
pool-1-thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
pool-1-thread-2, called closeSocket()
pool-1-thread-2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
pool-1-thread-2, called close()
pool-1-thread-2, called closeInternal(true)
2019-09-04 08:48:21.637 ERROR 1755 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Read exception localhost:63727:6000:51c3e8e9-194c-4f56-b238-960fa3b7c05c SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common
```

Any idea why the second Hello is another ClientHello, not ServerHello?

Comment: You have yet to mention what `CipherSuites` your client supports and which ones are supported by the server you are talking to. At least one of them has to match, else the ssl handshake won't succeed. `TLS` and `SSL` are using different cipher suites, that is why one may succeed and the other one does not. Also mention what java version you are using, as supported ciphers are different between versions.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question

Comment: This can mean that the server can't find its private key. I strongly recommend you get rid of the key oassword. Java doesn't handle that well, and you haven't configured it for the server anyway.

Comment: How did you obtain those ciphers? If possible I'd like to see a trace of the SSL Handshake. Check this [`link`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) on how to do that. It will be rather lengthy so you might want to omit the parts that do not look like something goes wrong. I am mostly interested in the cipher suites mentioned in the `ClientHello` and `ServerHello`.

Comment: [standard Java SSL/TLS debugging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-31B7E142-B874-46E9-8DD0-4E18EC0EB2CF) in particular try `javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake,keymanager` on server. Note for TLS<=1.2 (not 1.3) you need a ciphersuite enabled on both ends _and_ matching server key&cert; that first ciphersuite on your lists uses ECDHE_ECDSA and does not match your server.jks entry which is DSA because you didn't specify `-keyalg`, but you have several ciphersuites using DHE_DSS which _should_ match.

Comment: Updated with output from javax.net.debug

Comment: @second any update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an Application Context issue. I was defining the server SSL configuration beneath my `src/test/java`. One of my Autowired fields was pulling a client SSL configuration bean from `src/main/java`, not the server bean I thought it was. Hence the double ClientHellos.

Added a couple @Qualifiers to make sure my server config was being Autowired where I thought it was

Comment: So the problem was a different set of certificates (with different ciphers)? Or did the second `ClientHello` trigger the termination of the SSL Handshake?

Comment: It was the exact same certificate. The server was using the exact same keystore and truststore as the client